# How can I log in in an API with Python?

Tags: python, django

I have a question about how I can log into an API through Python code.
I want to "identify" the API login so that the user can see which invoices are pending, i.e. a user logs in with my Django login, which, at the same time, has to log in to the API.

Once logged into the API, I want the API to return the documents that have an id with its assigned tag.

I attach below the function that I have made and that connects me to the database. This function does not return any information from the API because of what I said, because first you have to identify which user is logged in.

```
@login_required
def f_facturaspendientes(request):
    # URL de la API a la que deseas conectarte
    url = 'http://host.docker.internal/api/v4/documents/'

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            # La solicitud fue exitosa, puedes procesar la respuesta aquí
            data = response.json()
            # Hacer algo con los datos de la API

            # Devuelve una respuesta JSON con los datos procesados
            return JsonResponse({'message': 'Solicitud exitosa', 'data': data})
        else:
            # La solicitud no fue exitosa, maneja el error aquí si es necesario
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Error en la solicitud', 'status_code': response.status_code})
    except Exception as e:
        # Maneja cualquier excepción que pueda ocurrir durante la solicitud
        return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})
```

I would like to display the documents that correspond to the tag that has been assigned to that user, i.e. user 1 can only see the tags with id 1; user 2 can only see the tags with id 4, ...
Note that the user admin, has to see all the tags.

Comment: There's no general answer to this question; it depends on the authentication mechanism the specific API uses.

Comment: For example, talking about the Mayan Edms API, which is an opersource platform that manages invoices

Comment: By reading your question, what I understand is that you need to implement some kind of user management in your application. I would also recommend you to add JWT tokens to get user info in each request.